# How to get UITextView to respect newlines in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, newline, uitextview

I have a simple app with a `UITextView` embedded into a `UIScrollView`.  Interface Builder won't let me add multiple newlines for spacing; when I hit return it sees that as "end of input" rather than appending the newline to the `UITextView`.

How can I get it to accept newlines for spacing?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Much simpler (and more IB based) than previous answers:

Just <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> It will send a newline to the `UITextView`.

Comment: Good to know.  I never even tried that.  I tried the normal Shift-Enter, but it does nothing.  Ctrl-Enter appears to work (the inspector shows blank lines), but it isn't respected in the view.

Comment: Works for UILabels with number of lines set to 0 as well.

Comment: At the first three tries ALT+Enter didn't work. But after some backspacing and adding ALT+Enter to a couple of lines it started woking. MAN I have been looking for this answer in a lot of articles :-)

Comment: the fundamental question is how did you find this :)

Comment: By mistake :-) Actually, it's something I try from time to time with text boxes, you'll see that in many cases where there is a multi-line text box that takes Enter key as the "Done" idiom, it will have some sort of key combination (usually ALT+Enter) for "next line".

Comment: _works like magic_ [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21654430/3577656)

Answer (score 10):

Write up your text in TextEdit, then copy/paste it in.

Answer (score 2):

As sbwoodside said, a text editor is the easiest way.

That said, ff you need more control, or it isn't *quite* working, don't use IB. Ideally, if you need any type of formatting for a long sting of text, do it programmatically.

Formatting in IB is horrible. I tried to add some "terms and conditions" in a UITextView and it was a real pain.

In the end it is easier than messing with IB...

Answer (score 1):

In IB Shift+Alt (Option)+Enter is as New paragraph

Comment: For me the ALT+Enter wasn't working... it would reflect the newline in the IB editor but the actual display wouldn't work.  Your key combination did exactly what I needed.  Thanks!