# Start a new line (paragraph) on a Label or TextView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I'd like to start a new line paragraph on a label and on a TextView but I can't find a way to do it via Interface Builder. Can you help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I assume you don't mean you just need a literal hyphen symbol '-' in the label and in the text view.

Comment: sorry, I just did a wrong "Italian to English" translation :) Title and content corrected

Comment: I don't think you can add a new line on a label but for a text view, it is `option + enter`. [`Source`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860940/how-to-get-uitextview-to-respect-newlines-in-interface-builder)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two steps :

- In Interface Builder you have to set the "number of lines" option to 0
- Use Cmd+Return (or Alt-Return) to make a carriage return