# iOS multiline label in Interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, line-breaks

How can I make a multiline `UILabel` in interface builder for iOS? I tried the `UITextView` but it didn't quite suit my needs.

How can I add multiline (text) in label?

Comment: Can you explain why id did not suite your needs? TextView with read-only is same as a multiline label.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be highlighted text color property.

Comment: For others visiting this question, dont follow accepted answer of setting lines to 5 or `n`. Instead set it to 0(Sort of infinity). Check vijay's answer below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can use `numberOfLines` property which defines **maximum** number of lines a label can have. By default, it's `1`. Setting it to `0` means the label will have **unlimited lines**.

You can do it in code:

```c
textLabel.numberOfLines = 5 // for example
```

Or in Interface Builder:

[image]

Comment: I tried, it works when I am writing the label, but when I press enter to accept it just all goes on one line.

Comment: And what's the `width` of your label?

Comment: Ok, I got it now, increased the height, that made it. Thanks!

Comment: You can set Lines to 0 for unlimited lines.

Comment: See also this answer which explains how to type a multi-line label into IB: http://stackoverflow.com/a/992511/893113

Comment: Setting the lines to 3 , align center and increase height did it thanks

Comment: BTW: Use Option+Enter for a new line

Answer (score 126):

Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a line in UILabel in Interface Builder/Storyboard.

Comment: Nice one. But "Q" isn't necessary I guess

Comment: Spot on ! Exactly what i have been trying to do. No messing up with code

Comment: @Oliver Logic it does not quit Xcode... You haven't read correctly. He said CONTROL+Q+ENTER (and not CMD+Q).. But Rendel is right only CONTROL+ENTER suffices here.

Comment: @Logic it does not quit Xcode... You haven't read correctly. He said CONTROL+Q+ENTER (and not CMD+Q).. But Rendel is right only CONTROL+ENTER suffices here.

Answer (score 48):

Thanks AppleVijay!

Also to call sizeToFit, like this:

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
```

The height will be automatically computed.

Comment: Note: UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated as of iOS6. Use [label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakWordWrapping]; instead.

Comment: Missing "By". label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Comment: use NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping instead of UILineBreakModeWordWrap for swift

Answer (score 12):

set width of label as u needed small then use IB to set line breaks to word wrap

or use with code like this

I found a solution.

One just has to add the following code:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 8):

Set number of lines zero for dynamic text information, it will be useful when your text are varying.

**Programatically (Swift 3)**

```
var label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "iOS\nmultiline\nlabel\nin\nInterface\nbuilder"
label.text = stringValue
label.numberOfLines = 0 // Set 0, if number of lines not specified.
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail // or .byWrappingWord
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8 . // It is not required but nice to have a minimum scale factor to fit text into label frame
```

---

**Using Inetrface Builder**

[image]

Note: It is not required to set `Minimum Font Scale`, but nice to have a minimum scale factor to fit text into label frame.

Comment: How can I make label height variable based on text in it ?

Comment: @Renascent - The 'Autoshrink' dropdown has another value in the list - Miminum font size, which may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Number of lines is visible in IB with Plain UILabels
set lines field as 0 . It will create multiple lines as per the provided space to the label.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7 (Xcode5) you shold set the lines of UILabel to `0` for unlimited multiple input in storyboard.
The most important is to set the `height of the UILabel` can hold the lines of input you are going to set.

Answer (score 0):

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

CGSize size =  [[[arrNewsFeed objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"c"]  sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(188, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                                     lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

textLabel.frame = (CGRect){.origin = cell.lblNewsDescription.frame.origin, .size = size};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the numberOfLines property equal to 0, the label will automatically adjust to the required number of lines of the given text.

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with this for a long time. 
I just wanted my label text to appear on the second line. But whatever I do, it would just overflow the UILabel box. For me, changing the autoresizing in size inspector worked. Simple fix.

May be someone might find it helpful who is looking for something similar.

Answer (score -2):

## For X-Code 7.2

1. -- Select UILabel
2. -- Attributes inspector
3. -- Text - Select Attributed

After this you can see some more attribute you can add into you label, in which you can also find number of **Lines**. Which make your label **multiline**.

[image: X-Code Image for a multiline UILabel]

Comment: Number of lines is visible in IB with Plain UILabels.