# How to insert new line \n from UILabel text which typed in IB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have id textInput and I insert new line(\n) OK with:

```
[textInput insertText:@"\n"];
```

But when input Text from label.text (Input in Interface Builder) ,it NOT OK. Just input \n text.

```
NSLog(@"%@",label.text);
[textInput insertText:label.text];
```

How to input special character when store it in label.text?

I don't want to compare `[inputStr isEqualToString:@"\\n"];`

*Log: \n

Thanks!

Comment: They are the same.  You're doing something wrong.

Comment: I put \n to label and [textInput insertText:label.text], NOT Work, just get \n text. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: Hint:  If you NSLog the data and it prints "\n" then it doesn't contain "\n".

Comment: They are the same.  You're doing something wrong.  (And you're not showing us your real code.)

Comment: I've edit, please check! Something wrong when input text from UILabel.text. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that label.text doesn't contain the newline code represented by "\n" but instead contains the characters "\" and "n".  This could presumably happen if you put "\n" into the text field of a label in Interface Builder, but if you code the C string "\n" or the Objective-C NSString @"\n" that combo will always be converted to newline.

Comment: You're right! So how to solve when input from IB?

Comment: Don't input your text with IB.  No need to.  Or, if you insist, translate the characters afterwards.  replaceOccurrencesOfStringWithString, IIRC.

Comment: That's depend on my App. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Try option-return or pasting in the newline.

Comment: Thanks! option-return is correct way!

Comment: option-return does work.

Comment: _works like magic_ [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21654430/3577656)

Comment: The best way :D :thumbsup:

Comment: For some reason, ctrl+return works, but option+ret doesn't.

Comment: number of lines should be 0

Answer (score 14):

@Hot Licks explained the reason well in comment.

The only way is

```
if ([self.mylabel.text isEqualToString:@"\\n"]) {

   [self.myTextView insertText:@"\n"];
}
```

Manually, use `ALT+ENTER`

Comment: Please see my edit. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: Sorry! Not work. Could you please do a test?

Comment: Thanks @Ramshad! I test this case before, but I have some special chars typed in IB, so that I don't want to compare all cases. I'm waiting!

Comment: Found \r in another answer and it works fine :-)